# tableview button creation dynamically in cell issue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to implement  dynamic button  on tableview cell .i am able to add the button but as per the requirement on last cell i don't want to add button  but its getting added there also as below mention screen capture

[image]

This is the requirement
my cellForRowAt indexPath code is below.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    if let _ = cell {
        print("cell is available")
    } else {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .left
    cell?.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
    let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom) as UIButton

    if cell?.textLabel?.text == "➕ Add Room" || list[indexPath.row] == "➕ Add Room"{
        btn.isHidden = true
        cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    }else{
        btn.frame = CGRect(x: 146, y: 0, width: 20, height: (cell?.frame.height)!)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)
        btn.tag = indexPath.row
        btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "delete.png"), for: .normal)
        cellx = list[btn.tag]
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(btn)
    }
    return cell!
}
```

and the result after this show below screen capture

[image]

i don't want to display the delete button in +Add Room row which is present in last row of table. 
Please suggest me how to get the out as mention in the requirement . i made a condition for the text ("Add Room Text") to shown in centre and successfully displaying in center.
Thanks in advance please help me to solve this issue

**2nd issue**

in this given list if i select "COPENHAGEN " and try to delete this , its deleting the upper content means BARCELONA file gets deleted.  i am not delete same seleted content from list .

Comment: Try adding breakpoint on if else condition and see if it goes inside if ?

Comment: Put this way

if indexPath.row == (list.count - 1) 
    {
        print("last row") // add your logic here
    }

Comment: Every time cell will dequeue, a new button will be added to your cell. You should handle this.

Comment: You just need to use btn.isHidden = false in else part

Comment: just create the button in UITableViewCell Class instead of cellForRowAtIndexPath and hide and show it according to the indexPath and also in prepareForReuse method make the button hide.

Comment: @Ankita Khare, Please check updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    if let _ = cell {
        print("cell is available")
    } else {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .left
    cell?.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
    let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom) as UIButton

    if cell?.textLabel?.text == "➕ Add Room" || list[indexPath.row] == "➕ Add Room"{
        for view in cell?.contentView.subviews as [UIView] {
            if let button = view as? UIButton {
               button.isHidden = true
            }
        }
        cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    }else{
        btn.frame = CGRect(x: 146, y: 0, width: 20, height: (cell?.frame.height)!)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)
        btn.tag = indexPath.row
        btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "delete.png"), for: .normal)
        cellx = list[btn.tag]
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(btn)
    }
    return cell!
}
```

Try this. It is because of your program flow. btn instance is created for every table rows and you set hidden just the instance of the btn for last row. Table cell reused dequeue cell even though you did not add created btn into table cell content view for the latest cell. So, you need to search the button from the content view and set hidden.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because UITableView reuses previously created cells. So for the last cell it takes already created cell with button inside.

It would be better to create your own subclass of UITableViewCell and use it.

But if you don't want to do that you can use this version of your code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    if let cell = cell {
        print("cell is available")
        // Remove previously created button from reused cell view
        if let button = cell.contentView.subviews.first(where: { (view: UIView) -> Bool in
            view.isKind(of: UIButton.self)
        }) {
            button.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    } else {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .left
    cell?.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

    if indexPath.row == (list.count - 1) {
        cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    } else {
        let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom) as UIButton
        btn.frame = CGRect(x: 146, y: 0, width: 20, height: (cell?.frame.height)!)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)
        btn.tag = indexPath.row
        btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "delete.png"), for: .normal)
        cellx = list[btn.tag]
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(btn)
    }
    return cell!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! cell

 if indexPath.row == (list.count - 1) {
        btn.isHidden = true
        cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    }else{
        btn.isHidden = false
        btn.frame = CGRect(x: 146, y: 0, width: 20, height: (cell?.frame.height)!)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)
        btn.tag = indexPath.row
        btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "delete.png"), for: .normal)
        cellx = list[btn.tag]
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(btn)
    }
```

I have not tested this above code just made some minor changes maybe it will work :)
If not so please let me know.

EDIT1:
Answer updated

Comment: @AnkitaKhare would you please debug `if indexPath.row == (list.count - 1) ` line returns `true` for `false`  for the last case?